Virtual energy levels in atoms and 2-photon absorption
Two-photon atom excitation is a very well known and widely utilized tool in nonlinear spectroscopy.  The physics of it consists in transition to a "virtual" energy level $E$ by absorbing a photon of energy $\omega_1$ from one laser beam , and then going to an excited level $E_n$ by absorbing the second photon of energy $\omega_2$, $\omega_1+\omega_2 = E_n-E_0$.
Q: Why does not the inverse process happen, i.e., first emitting a photon of energy $\omega_2$ and going to a "virtual" level $E$ and then emitting a second photon of energy $\omega_1$ and going into the ground state?
Remark: the two-photon absorption is a second-order process that is suppressed by a power of coupling constant. One has to have high intensity field in order to have such process. The "inverse" process described above is also a second order process, and therefore highly unlikely (much less likely than direct transition to the ground state). But its probability is not zero. The matrix element of this process is related to the matrix element of the above direct process.

It does happen.  That's the dominant decay mode for $2S\rightarrow1S$ in hydrogen.  Two-photon spontaneous decays are just rarely observed unless there are symmetries that rule out the allowed one-photon, first-order forbidden one-photon, and other lower-order decay processes.  The small matrix element (and sometimes phase space issues) make two-photon decay processes quite slow.  The  $2S\rightarrow1S$ lifetime is about $10^{8}$ times the  $2P\rightarrow1S$ lifetime in hydrogen.
The difference with an absorption process is that you can increase the field intensity to make it more and more likely, but that is not possible with a spontaneous decay.  Spontaneous decays are essentially stimulated by the vacuum fluctuations of the electromagnetic field modes.
